# regular expression matching and replacing pvalue strings

Tags: regex, r

Hoping this will make sense.

I have a string of pvalues of different lengths (due to rounding), where very large and small pvalues get stored as `1.0(some number of 0s corresponding to the length of rounding)`, and `0.0(some number of 0s corresponding to the length of rounding)`, respectively.

I want to match two sets of patterns:

First:
`"(1.)(string of zeros of any length)"`
and change it to `"> 0.(sting of nines the same length as the string of zeros)"`

Second
`"(0.)(string of zeros of any length)"`
and change it to `"< 0.(string of zeros the length of the input minus one)1`.

So if we have the following input:

```
pvals<-c("1.000","1.00","0.00000","0.123","0.6","0.0")
```

I would expect to return:

```
> expectedOutput
[1] "> 0.999"   "> 0.99"    "< 0.00001" "0.123"     "0.6"       "< 0.1"
```

I've been trying to use gsub, but I have very very little understanding of the more complex use of regular expressions I don't understand how to allow for any length of a certain character (0), and then how to replace with the same number of a new character (in the case of 1.0s), or that number minus 1 (in the case of 0.0s)

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: i think the the output for the first element is `< 0.999`

Comment: Not sure what's the difference between `1.000` and `1.00`. Neither between `0.00000`, `0.0` and just `0`

Comment: No, I would like all strings that start with "1." to then become "> 0."

Comment: This is just a simplification of the problem. The problem is that I will receive input of either 0.00000 and 0.0 and I need to keep the integrity of the input.

Comment: @AvainashRaj  Ah, my input/output was correct but my rules were flipped. Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for pointing that out. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
> pvals<-c("1.000","1.00","0.00000","0.123","0.6","0.0")
> x <- gsub("(?:^1\\.|\\G)\\K0(?=0*$)", "9", pvals, perl=T)
> m <- gsub("^1\\.", "> 0.", x)
> gsub("^(0\\.0*)0$", "< \\11", m)
[1] "> 0.999"   "> 0.99"    "< 0.00001" "0.123"    
[5] "0.6"       "< 0.1"
```

Comment: This looks great. Well, unfortunately for me, it looks like a monkey pounding on a keyboard, but it works very well. Do you have any sort of reference where I can learn regex to this level?

Comment: i learned all the regex stuff   from SO itself. You could refer [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) site..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **gsubfn** package to do this as well.

```
pvals <- c('1.000', '1.00', '0.00000', '0.123', '0.6', '0.0')

f <- proto(fun = function(this, x, y) 
   if (x==1) paste0('> 0.', paste(rep(9, nchar(y)), collapse = '')) 
   else paste0('< 0.', paste(rep(0, nchar(y)-1), collapse = ''), 1))

gsubfn('([01])\\.(0+)', f, pvals)
# [1] "> 0.999"   "> 0.99"    "< 0.00001" "0.123"     "0.6"       "< 0.1"
```